# Vue3: Неверное комментирование в <style> в VS Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, scss, vue3, комментарии

Разрабатываю на Vue 3 в VS Code.

Внутри файла Vue есть три тега: `<template>`, `<script>`, `<style>`.
При нажатии на `ctrl+/` у меня комментируется код. Внутри тегов `<template>` и `<script>` всё работает правильно: в `<template>` комментарий выглядит как `<-- -->` вокруг выделения, в `<script>` он выглядит как `//` перед выделенными строками.

Но в теге `<style>` при нажатии на `ctrl+/` используется `<-- -->`, а нужно, чтобы использовался `//` аналогично такому в `<script>`.

Где я могу это настроить?